# Using handlebars template - jquery data not properly rendering

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am getting json data, using i am manipulation using jquery method to append my template. i am getting data properly but i am not get the the element append.. what is wrong here..

my html :

```
<script id="header-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="loginInfo"> <a href="#">{{name}}</a> | <a href="#">Logout</a> </div>
    </script>
```

myfunction:

```
var manupulate = function(data){

        var template = Handlebars.compile($("#header-template").html());

        $.each(data, function(key,data){
            if(key==="name"){
                $("header").append(template(data));//it is rendering but i didn't see the name value.. console.log(data) - works fine.
            }
        })
    }
```

what is wrong here.. any one help me?

Comment: just note: make sure you have many variables named data

Comment: nope, there is no instance like data.. only one key i have. in case of consoling i am getting correct name as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass an object but not a string to the template function:

```
$("header").append(template({name: data}));
```

I think it's better to rename the data since It's so confusing.